# Generating vector of number of decreasing order

Tags: r

I want to make a vector of numbers (float) randomly drawn between a range (40.0 - 12.0) in decreasing order. How can I do that?

I've tried using the following:

```
unique(cummax(sample.int(40)))
```

But it doesn't let me specify the length. Also I want to sample float numbers and not integers. Lastly, I want the numbers to be from 40.0 to 12.0 in decreasing order. How can I achieve that in R.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `runif`, where we can specify the range and then `sort` it in decreasing order

```
n <- 10
sort(runif(n, min = 12, max = 40), decreasing = TRUE)
# [1] 38.7 37.8 35.5 29.8 25.9 24.2 19.5 18.0 12.3 12.2
```

To make a plot we can do

```
n <- 100
nums <- sort(runif(n, min = 12, max = 40), decreasing = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)

data.frame(n = 1:n, nums) %>%
   ggplot() + aes(n, nums) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]

Or in base R

```
plot(1:n, nums, type = "l")
```

---

Here is something closer to expected output with `dexp`

```
nums <- seq(12, 40, length.out=100)
data.frame(x= 1:length(nums), y = dexp(nums, 0.65)) %>%
    ggplot() + aes(x, y) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: And is it possible to make a curve that I've attached (I've edited the question). Because what you've said produces a linear line. I'm just trying to learn how much we could actually get done with generating random numbers in R. I'm sorry if my questions are super basic.

Comment: John, you can create the curve by plotting the numbers generated by Ronak on the y-axis and on the x-axis plotting `1:n`.

Comment: @John yes, as caldwellst said, I have updated the plot code. You can check now.

Comment: @Ronak this graph still looks linear to me even when I increase n. I was asking if you could make a curve like I've shown in the question where the curve drops a lot in the beginning and then decreases very little. Maybe it's not possible to do it with random numbers?

Comment: yes, I don't think random numbers will help you in getting the graph you need. Maybe you need inverse exponential graph.

Comment: @John Do you need numbers between 12 and 40 necessarily ?

Comment: Yes I want it to be between 12 and 40.

Comment: I have updated the post which generates plot similar to yours see if it helps.